# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Tags: javascript, discord

Olá, eu estou fazendo um bot para o Discord (discord.js), e apareceu isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o `index.js`:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logado como ${client.user.tag}!`)
  client.user.setActivity("5 Comandos Disponíveis!", {
    type: "PLAYING"
  })
})

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm" || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
  let input = args.shift()

  if (input === "ping") {
    return message.channel.send("Pong!")
  }

  if (input === "beep") {
    return message.channel.send('Boop.');
  }

  if (input === "botinfo") {
    return 
    message.channel.send('Olá, eu sou a **Estela!**\nFui criado por `Zumoka` e atualmente tenho 5 comandos disponíveis.');
  }

  if (input === "serverinfo") {
    return message.channel.send(`Nome do servidor: ${message.guild.name}\nMembros no total: ${message.guild.memberCount}`)
  }

  if (input === "userinfo") {
    return message.channel.send(`Seu nome de usuário: ${message.author.username}\nSeu ID: ${message.author.id}`)
  }
})

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));

const EstelaClient = require("./src/EstelaClient")
const NewClient = new EstelaClient()
NewClient.startBot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente a porta que vc inicializou já está em uso.

Ai você tem duas opções, ou mudar a aplicação para outra porta nessa constante port, ou matar a aplicação que já está utilizando a porta 3000.